# How to apply rules defined in a sql table to other tables

Tags: sql, rules, impala

**Ok so, I have a table that has a set of user defined rules that classify items like so**

```
class_id    team_category   league_category    mascot_category
1          NULL            AA                 BIRD
2          WINNER          AAA                NULL
```

**and then I have a list of teams like so:**

```
team_id    team_category   league_category    mascot_category
9          LOSER           AA                 BIRD
10         WINNER          AAA                CAT
11         NULL            A                  BIRD
```

What I need is some type of SQL command that would join the two to tell me which teams are in which class.

I can't figure how to join the tables properly so I get something like

```
 team_id   class_id 
 9         1 
 10        2
```

I appreciate any help in advance.

Also note I'm actually using a limited SQL command set (cloudera impala) so the more simple the better.

Answer (score 0):

You can join on multiple criteria, so something like this would work for you:

```
SELECT teams.team_id, rules.class_id
FROM teams
INNER JOIN rules
  ON (teams.team_category = rules.team_category OR rules.team_category IS NULL)
    AND (teams.league_category = rules.league_category OR rules.league_category IS NULL)
    AND (teams.mascot_category = rules.mascot_category OR rules.mascot_category IS NULL)
```

That provides the output you were looking for. [SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/87499/3).